# How to pull through the event value on Add To Cart event in Google Analytics goals?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, shopify, e-commerce, google-datalayer

I have a Shopify store set-up and have Enhanced Ecommerce set-up and linked to Google Analytics, however I am having trouble being able to set/capture the add to cart event value. Here is a screenshot of my goal set-up within GA:

[image]

When I simulate the event on the website product page and run a Google Analytics debug I can see that the event fires and add to carts are being tracked within GA. However, I want to capture the value of the product being added. The event firing seems to output all of the data I need within debug in the console, but I am at a loss as to how to link the value to ATC event.

Am I correct in thinking that the value field within the goal set-up on GA needs something there? Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value indicated in the goal configuration is relative to the value of the event, not to the value of the product added to the cart.

Therefore if the event has no value, it will not be able to know that you want that value to be that of the product added to the cart. For this reason in the event tag you must define category, action (possibly the label) and the **value**. You will need to retrieve this value from the page code and pass it to Analytics as value in the event. At this point, once you have set the goal to activate on that particular event, by activating the option shown in your picture, it will also retrieve the value of the event as you set it.

[EDIT - more details]

When you send an event you can define a value to pass to Analytics. If you want this value to be the price of the product, you must retrieve it and value the value parameter of the event.

The '*Value*' field in '*Event conditions*' is a condition for activating the goal (if you don't want to consider it as a condition, leave it blank). While, if you want the event value (in your case the product price) to be used by Analytics as the conversion value for that event, just activate the toggle.

Comment: Thanks Michele. So I'm still a little confused, are you saying that within the options in the picture above I should leave the value blank? And then I should set the event value on the front end when the event fires and sends data to GA? For context, I'm using the Add To Cart goal template within GA, so possible I need to set-up the firing of the event manually rather than using a template?